# Choosing of specialisation in ECE

Tags: digital-logic, communication, electromagnetic

I have completed my UG in ECE. but did not focus much. i am confused on how to  chose my specialisation for PG.

Comment: Bhagyasree P - Hi, Sorry but this type of question is better suited to a discussion forum, and is not a good fit on Stack Exchange. You can see more about site rules & etiquette in the [tour] & [help]. This site is generally for [electronics design & related topics](/help/on-topic) i.e. technical questions, whose answers don't change. Questions about careeer / education are often very localised to a particular country / region / time, and may not apply elsewhere, or as things change in the future. It also varies by person. || All that make such questions a poor fit for this site.